# Laravel Redis Job Batching: Incomplete Batches Despite Successful Job Execution and Empty Pending Jobs Queue

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, job-batching

I am utilizing the job batching feature in Laravel with Redis.

Upon dispatching 30,000 jobs in a batch, I have recorded the sequence number of each job within its processing function. Upon reviewing the logs, I can confirm that all 30,000 jobs were successfully processed. However, the 'pending_jobs' column in the 'job_batches' table consistently displays jobs pending for processing, and the batch remains incomplete.

I have checked the count of pending jobs both at the job dispatch initiation and after the batch jobs have been executed in Redis using the command:

```bash
LLEN laravel_database_queues:default
```

The result indicates a seemingly lower count of jobs in Redis during dispatch compared to the dispatched count. Despite this, all 30,000 jobs are processed successfully.

Furthermore, the count after the job completion shows 0, signifying that no jobs are awaiting processing.

Interestingly, when reducing the number of dispatched jobs to 10,000, the process functions without any issues.

What could be the potential cause of this discrepancy in Laravel and Redis job batching? Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

This is my code:

```php
// App\Jobs\UpdateWorkingHistorySalary
public function handle(WorkingHistoryService $workingHistoryService): void
{
   if (!($this->batch() instanceof Batch)) {
       return;
   }

   Log::debug('COUNT: ' . $this->count);
   // Some code ...
}
```

```php
// App\Controllers\AllowanceController
$batch = Bus::batch([])->dispatch();

$count = 0;

WorkingHistory::query()
    ->where('date_working', '>=', $startDate->toDateString())
    ->where('date_working', '<', $endDate->toDateString())
    ->where('work_kpi', '!=', 0)
    ->chunk(5000, function (Collection $workingHistories) use ($batch, &$count) {
        $jobs = $workingHistories->lazy()->map(function ($workingHistory) use (&$count) {
            return new UpdateWorkingHistorySalary($workingHistory, ++$count);
        });

        $batch->add($jobs->all());

        unset($jobs);
    });
```